# SQL Server: add ranking to nested selects

Tags: sql, sql-server, nested, ranking, rank

I am using the following stored procedure which works fine so far.

Can someone tell me how I have to change this in order to get a ranking for each of the nested Selects ?
What I am looking for is a new rank that gets added to each of them so that every nested Select starts with 1, 2, 3 etc.

My SP:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
            SELECT 
            (
                SELECT      policy, 
                            COUNT(*) AS count0
                FROM        Log_PE 
                WHERE       CONVERT(DATE, dateEsc, 120) >= CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()), 112) + '01', 112)
                GROUP BY    policy
                ORDER BY    count0 desc, policy
                FOR XML PATH('currentMonth'), ELEMENTS, TYPE
            )
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
            (
                SELECT      policy, 
                            COUNT(*) AS count1
                FROM        Log_PE 
                WHERE       CONVERT(DATE, dateEsc, 120) >= CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()), 112) + '01', 112)
                GROUP BY    policy
                ORDER BY    count1 desc, policy
                FOR XML PATH('prevMonth2'), ELEMENTS, TYPE
            )
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
            (
                SELECT      policy, 
                            COUNT(*) AS count2
                FROM        Log_PE 
                WHERE       CONVERT(DATE, dateEsc, 120) >= CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE()), 112) + '01', 112)
                GROUP BY    policy
                ORDER BY    count2 desc, policy
                FOR XML PATH('prevMonth3'), ELEMENTS, TYPE
            )
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
            (
                SELECT      policy, 
                            COUNT(*) AS count3
                FROM        Log_PE 
                WHERE       CONVERT(DATE, dateEsc, 120) >= CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE()), 112) + '01', 112)
                GROUP BY    policy
                ORDER BY    count3 desc, policy
                FOR XML PATH('prevMonth4'), ELEMENTS, TYPE
            )
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
            (
                SELECT      policy, 
                            COUNT(*) AS count4
                FROM        Log_PE 
                WHERE       CONVERT(DATE, dateEsc, 120) >= CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), DATEADD(month, -4, GETDATE()), 112) + '01', 112)
                GROUP BY    policy
                ORDER BY    count4 desc, policy
                FOR XML PATH('prevMonth5'), ELEMENTS, TYPE
            )
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
            (
                SELECT      policy, 
                            COUNT(*) AS count5
                FROM        log_PE 
                WHERE       CONVERT(DATE, dateEsc, 120) >= CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), DATEADD(month, -5, GETDATE()), 112) + '01', 112)
                GROUP BY    policy
                ORDER BY    count5 desc, policy
                FOR XML PATH('prevMonth5'), ELEMENTS, TYPE
            )
        ) AS Data(XmlData)
    FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
```

END

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to achieve. Can you illustrate some data output pls?

Comment: Are there a known number of select statements? Or do you want this to be independent of the how many there are (i.e. recursive)

Comment: Thanks. Currently there are always 6 nested selects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this column to each of your nested selects:

```
rank() over(order by count(*) desc, policy) [Rank]
```

Comment: Thanks. Where do I put that ? Just add it above the xml line for each select ?

Comment: If you want to make it so that "every nested Select starts with 1, 2, 3 etc", I'd put it right before the policy line in each subquery.

Comment: One more question on this: How can I order the whole xml string by this new [Rank] ?

Comment: You are quite welcome! Happy to help. :)

It should already be ordered by the Rank since the Rank is ordered by count(*) desc,policy, and that is what your sub-queries are ordered by. You could replace your order by clause in each sub-query with `order by [Rank]` and it should have the same effect.

Comment: Sorry, I tested with adding ORDER BY [Rank] to the main select as I need this over-all but this creates an error 'Invalid column name'.

Comment: Yeah, that won't work because after you have converted the results to XML, there is no Rank column name. Sorting within each sub-query doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks, it is already sorted correctly within the nested Selects, I was just trying to get it sorted over-all. Never mind, I think I found a work-around for this part.